# How to use .htaccess to remove filename and only show parameters

Tags: .htaccess

My website page what I am recently working on is `mydomain.com/page.php?cat=cover&brand=Nokia`.

I want to display the url something like this - 
`mydomain.com/cover/nokia`

Meaning I don't want to show the page name i.e. `page.php` and hide the parameter names as well. Also the last parameter is optional.

If somebody can help me doing this, will be a great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?cat=$1&brand=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ page.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```